# Screen is entirely black. How do I diagnose what is wrong?

Tags: screen, unbricking

**Phone details**

Pixel 5a. Purchased April 2022. The display glass shattered in Jan 2023, and I got it replaced through a 3rd party repair. Only the glass was repaired, not the display unit. The phone worked fine after.

**The problem**

2-3 weeks ago the screen cracked, but the phone was working fine so I just continued to use it. Earlier this week I was watching a video on the phone when it stalled. I thought it might have overheated so I just switched the display off with the power button and waited. But since then, the display has been completely unresponsive.

**What I have tried**

- Long-pressing the power button (or combination of power and volume up/down) does not bring any response.
- If I connect the phone to a PC (I use Ubuntu), the PC detects and recognises the phone as a Pixel 5a. But if I try to interact with it I get an error message saying `Unable to access "Pixel 5a". Unable to open MTP device "001,007"`
- If I run the command `adb devices` then I get no devices attached.
- If I scan my fingerprint, then there's a slight vibration, which is familiar to how the phone would respond under normal circumstances.
- If I insert my SIM and try calling the number, then at the caller end, I can hear a ring. However, the phone instrument shows no indication of a call being received, i.e. there is no vibration or ringing from the instrument.

I originally thought the phone was bricked, but based on the fingerprint and the call going through, I wonder if it's just that the display unit is fried but the instrument is otherwise fine. What can I do to find out?

Comment: Correct, its the display unit

Comment: "If I insert my SIM and try calling the number, then at the caller end, I can hear a ring"  When you turn that phone off, you will also hear that ring... That is just an indication that you are _connected_ to the network of your provider.

Comment: @Luuk: Yes. My assumption is that if I am connected to the network with the Pixel 5a, the instrument is working. By contrast, even if a working instrument is switched off with the SIM inside, calling that number will result in a message from the network provider saying "the number you are trying to call is switched off", or something to that effect.

Comment: This sounds like a bad display, the phone is not "bricked"... but there is a well known issue with the 5a where a motherboard problem causes the display not to work. https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/11833075?hl=en